# MFC application title

Tags: mfc

I am creating a simple clock application using MFC. My application title appears as follows : "CLOCK - [CLOCK1]". How do I reset it to simply "CLOCK"? 
FYI, I have enabled the Document-View architecture.

Comment: When I need to do a simple app like that, I bypass Document-View altogether and just start with a dialog.

Answer (score 7):

Put in this override of the MFC title:

```
void CMainFrame::OnUpdateFrameTitle(BOOL bAddToTitle)
{
SetWindowText(L"CLOCK");
}
```

Comment: if you have a MDI application, you may need to override `CChildFrame::OnUpdateFrameTitle()`

Comment: That didnt work. Overriding the CMainFrame::OnUpdateFrameTitle only caused the title to change from CLOCK - [CLOCK1] to [CLOCK1]foo, "foo" being the override. I still need to get rid of CLOCK1.

Comment: @EdwardClements Can you please tell me how to override CMainFrame::OnUpdateFrame? I called SetWindowText("CLO") inside the overridden funtion, but that didnt change anything.

Comment: It looks like you need to do more, see my answer

Comment: In your doc initialization, you can also do `SetTitle(_T(""));` if the title of the doc is not important, because CLOCK1 seems to me it is the doc's title.

Answer (score 6):

There's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14295450/1850797), but I feel that the following solution is more "proper".

In addition to overriding `CMainFrame::OnUpdateFrameTitle()`, you also need to override `CMainFrame::PreCreateWindow()` as below:

```
BOOL CMainFrame::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{   cs.style &= ~FWS_ADDTOTITLE;
    return CFrameWndEx::PreCreateWindow(cs); // replace CFrameWndEx by CFrameWnd if
}                                            // your CMainFrame is based on CFrameWnd
```

A note: it is better to use `AfxSetWindowText(m_hWnd, _T("foo"))` instead of `SetWindowText(_T("foo"))` to avoid excessive flicker, it checks that the text is different before setting the window text.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in visual editor by clicking on a your window and typing a title.
Or you can add this code in function OnInitDialog

`this->SetWindowText(L"CLOCK");`

Comment: By my own experience, your answer will not work on his case. Because the format of the title he present has is "CLOCK - [CLOCK1]", which is the format "WindowText - lpszDocName" outputed by `void CFrameWnd::UpdateFrameTitleForDocument(LPCTSTR lpszDocName)` called by `void CFrameWnd::OnUpdateFrameTitle(BOOL bAddToTitle)`

Your `SetWindowText` will be overriden by the process I described, so implementing the `OnUpdateFrameTitle` function override on the main frame is the way to go.